# Error symfony Key "" for array with keys "..." does not exist

Tags: symfony, twig

I need some help with this error

```
Key "dateFinValidite" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22" does not exist.
```

I use this here:

```
{{ include('/Unite/inc.listUnites.html.twig', {'unites': unites.dateFinValidite|filter(u => u > "now"|date('U'))}) }}
```

What I want is to show only avalaible date.

I tried to make a loop of this include but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unites` is an array and you are trying to access his `dateFinValidite` attribute of it which is, i assume, an attribute of each entry of this array. This is not an error related to symfony or twig.
This is why you get this error.

The proper code would be something like this :

```
{% for unite in unites %}

    {% if unite.dateFinValidite > "now"|date('U') %}
        {{ include('/Unite/inc.unite_item.html.twig', {'unite': unite) }}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

OR something like this

```
{% for unite in unites|filter(unite => unite.dateFinValidite > "now"|date('U')) %}
        {{ include('/Unite/inc.unite_item.html.twig', {'unite': unite) }}    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you that savec my life, i have a better understanding of this now

Comment: "*This is not an error related to symfony or twig*" - It kinda is, if you don't enable strict variables in twig, then this error wouldn't appear and would output an empty string - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ex8uhi) (You can toggle the strict settings under more options in the demo)

Comment: I mean, it is more php related knowledge more than twig or symfony.
| filter dosnt do much more than array_filter php function. Since Twig is coded in php